# How can I improve this code with nested loops?

Tags: python, loops

I have a function that count number of collisions between two point in each frame.
I have no idea how to improve this very slow code.

```
     #data example
     #[[89, 814, -77.1699249744415, 373.870468139648, 0.0], [71, 814, -119.887828826904, 340.433287620544, 0.0]...]

    def is_collide(data, req_dist):
        #req_dist - minimum distance when collision will be count

        temp = data 

        temp.sort(key=Measurements.sort_by_frame)
        max_frame = data[-1][1]
        min_frame = data[0][1]
        collissions = 0

        # max_frame-min_frame approximately 60000
        # the slowest part
        for i in range(min_frame, max_frame):
            frames = [line for line in temp if line[1] == i]
            temp = [line for line in temp if line[1] != i]
            l = len(frames)

            for j in range(0, l, 1):
                for k in range(j+1, l, 1):
                    dist = ((frames[j][2] - frames[k][2])**2 + (frames[j][3]-frames[k][3])**2)**0.5
                    if dist < req_dist:
                        collissions += 1

        return collissions
```

Comment: Its error free and you only want to increase the performance right?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum verifiable example with short examples of data, expected input and output?

Comment: you are mutating data when you ```temp.sort()``` FYI

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate place where to ask

Comment: what is the value of req_dist?

Comment: avoid calculating the square root within the loop by checking the square of `dist`: `def is_collide(data, req_dist):` `req_dist **= 2` ... `dist = (frames[j][2] - frames[k][2])**2 + (frames[j][3]-frames[k][3])**2`

Comment: i add data example and comment beginning of the slowest part

Comment: req_dist - distance when collision is recognized

Comment: if you are replying to my suggestion, read it again. It's useless to keep calculating the square within the loop. Use the square of `req_dist` and compare to that.

Comment: why use two lists comps instead of a single loop using if/else and appending to appropriate lists?

Comment: Also bisecting would probably be an idea as your data is sorted

Comment: Pynchia, I`ve done as you said but they are approximately equal or improvment is not significant. (running time: ~180 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Computing distance between every pair of points is expensive: an O(n**2) operation.  In general, that can be very expensive even for small n.

I would suggest stepping back and seeing if there is a better data structure to do this::

1. Quad-trees: Check the wikipedia article on Quad-Trees.  These can be used for collision detection possibly.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree
2. In Jon Bentley's book "Programming Pearls", Section 2, column 5 is very relevant to this.  He describes all the optimizations needed for computing something similar in a N-body problem.  I strongly suggest reading that for some ideas.

Having said that, I think there are some places where you could make some fairly simply improvements and get some modest speed-up.

1) The distance computation with an exponentiation (actually the square root) is an expensive operation.
2) You use n**2 to compute a square, when it's probably faster to just multiply n by itself.

You could replace it with a temp (and multiply by itself), but even better: you don't need it!  As long as all distances are computed the same way (without the **.5), you can compare them.   In other words, distances can be compared without the sqrt operation, as long as you only need the relative value.  I answered a similar question here:

[Fastest way to calculate Euclidean distance in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150038/fastest-way-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-in-c/32150223#32150223)

Hope this helps!