# How to approximate Euclidean distance on the integer plane, without overflow?

Tags: euclidean-distance, integer-arithmetic

I'm working on a platform that has only integer arithmetic.  The application uses geographic information, and I'm representing points by *(x, y)* coordinates where *x* and *y* are distances measured in meters.
As an approximation, I want to compute the Euclidean distance between two points.  But to do this I have to square distances, and with 32-bit integers, the largest distance I can represent is 32 kilometers.  Not good.
My needs are more on the order of 1000 kilometers.  But I'd like to be able to resolve distances on a scale smaller than 30 meters.

Hence my question: **how can I compute Euclidean distance, using only integer arithmetic, without overflow**, on distances whose squares don't fit in a single word?

ETA: I would like to be able to compute distances, but I might settle for being able to compare them.

Comment: You actually want to *really* compute the distances, or compare distances? Hope you won't kill a kitten when you see my comment. :)

Comment: @gsamaras Prefer to compute, but will settle for comparison.  All kittens alive and happy!

Comment: Is there a memory limit ? I've done something similar by precomputing values in a grid and storing those then doing an approximate bilinear interpolation.

Comment: There are some clever algorithms in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506404/fast-hypotenuse-algorithm-for-embedded-processor/3506633).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps comparing the [octagonal distance approximation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Distance_approximations) would be sufficient?

Slightly more up to date is [this article on fast approximate distance functions](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the *square root out of play*, so that I can approximate the Euclidean distance. However, when comparing distances, this approach gives you 100% accuracy, since the comparison would be the same if you squared the distances.

I am pretty sure about that, since I had use that approach when searching for nearest neighbours in high dimensional spaces. You can check my code and the theory in [kd-GeRaF](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/projects/#geraf).

Comment: Did you meant 'leave the _square root_ out of the play'? The distance I found [here](https://github.com/gsamaras/kd_GeRaF/blob/6e24152c28e258ed68c304489e9ee8608517268f/source/Division_Euclidean_space.h#L221) calculates the square.

Comment: @minusone yes, good catch! Answer updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use fixed point calculation using integers and then the distance approximation is already not too complicated.

- [fixed point calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11816993/5770014)
- [distance approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26607206/5770014)
- [Fast Approximate Distance Functions by Rafael Baptista](https://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml)

#### First step is to choose some fixed point representation for our needs:

For example in case we need a number range for 1000km with 1m resolution we can use 20bits that would be 2^20 = 1,048,576. So we have around 10bits for fractions.

#### Then we need to implement the approximation we choose:

For example in case we select the following approximation:

> h ≈ b (1 + 0.337 (a/b)) = b + 0.337 a  AND  assuming  0 ≤ a ≤ b

We will implement as follows:

```c
  int32_t dx = (x1 > x2 ? x1 - x2 : x2 - x1);
  int32_t dy = (y1 > y2 ? y1 - y2 : y2 - y1);
  int32_t a = dx > dy ? dy : dx;
  int32_t b = dx > dy ? dx : dy;
  int32_t h = b + (345 * a >> 10);      /* 345.088 = 0.337 * 2^10 */
```

#### About overflow:

Adding two <+20.0> positive numbers will result a maximum of <+21.0> number. That is Ok.

The multiplication is also safe while we use numbers in a range of -1..1. In this case the result will also remain in the same range. In our case <+20.0> * <+0.10> will result <+20.10> numbers. That we convert back to <+20.0>.

There is one step here we need to pay attention. During the multiplication we will get temporary a number with <+20.10> that is already near to our 32bits limit.

#### Exact calculation

We can also calculate the exact distance using the following consideration:

> h = b sqrt(1 + (a/b)^2) AND assuming 0 < b ≤ a

In tis case we also need to calculate the square root:

- [square root](https://github.com/chmike/fpsqrt/blob/master/fpsqrt.c#L51)

In case the `a/b` still significantly larger than one or too large to calculate the square of it, we can simplify the calculation to:

> h = a

See the implementation [here](https://onlinegdb.com/lWX24Jwc1)